# Recognize efficiently if a parameter was used in the command line calling a script in csh

Tags: if-statement, command-line-arguments, csh

I have a csh script that is called like this : <Script_name> -OptionA -OptionB -OptionC
Each one of this option may or may not be used, when the script is called, and they can be in any order.
I would like to be able to test easily in a if condition (or equivalent), if OptionX is present at any given position : $argv[?], $1 $2, .... ?

I tried something like this but it is not working :

```
if($?OptionB) then
    #Do anything
endif
```

Can you think of an efficient (compact) solution to test existence of the option at any argument of the command line ?

Have a good day, Julien

Comment: It's possible a `while` loop with a `switch` statement on the `$argv` (and related) variables could help. Can't spare the time to experiment with it. Good luck.

Comment: I do recall using `$?var` to test if `var` has a value. Searching elsewhere for tutorials may help. But, you're missing a space char between `if($?OptionA)`. This [csh tutorial](https://grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html) is very good, and should get you with some  postable code. Also try searching `csh getopts` on the web. Good luck.

Comment: I couldn't resist. While I really recall using getopt in csh code ~30 yrs ago, I could be kidding myself. I can't find a good example on the web, I'm getting `getopt a:b:cde opt`: Ambiguous.` when trying to run `while (`getopt a:b:cde opt`)` from an unanswer question elsewhere on the web (which seems perfectly reasonable). BUT anyway, unless you are truly mandated by a contract to deliver this in csh stop wasting your time and use a more "modern" shell, `bash` or `zsh`. Sadly `ksh` is becoming a niche item. Good luck.

Comment: If you really must stick w the csh, find a copy of Anderson & Anderson's `The Unix C Shell Field Guide` which is truly excellent example of introductory tech writing that should make modern editors hand their heads in shame. AND it's printed on good paper, my copy hasn't yellowed a bit (Things were always so much better in the mid 90s! (-;! LOL). (Sorry!)).

Comment: [This one](https://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/62709-getopt-getopts-csh.html)  isn't working, but it is all I have the time to find. If you can fix it, you'll have learned a lot. To get past `Ambiguous`, I tried `set myArgs = \`getopt ....\`; echo "myArgs=$myArgs"; while ( $myArgs ) ...` which is where I got stuck. I think it is solvable, or possibly it will work in a different OS's `csh`, (Ubuntu on WSL2, no). Good luck.